# Integer array Get difference between two highest numbers

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a `List<int[]>` that I populated by splitting an integer array into 4 groups. Now I need to get the difference of the two highest numbers in the array. I tried Array.Sort but I am stuck on how to continue.

**What I have done so far?**

```
    public static void solution(int[] T)
    {
        List<int[]> splitted = new List<int[]>();//This list will contain all the splitted arrays.
        int lengthToSplit = T.Length / 4;

        int arrayLength = T.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i = i + lengthToSplit)
        {
            int[] val = new int[lengthToSplit];

            if (arrayLength < i + lengthToSplit)
            {
                lengthToSplit = arrayLength - i;
            }
            Array.Copy(T, i, val, 0, lengthToSplit);
            splitted.Add(val);
        }

        //this is the part where I must get the difference between the two highest numbers in an integer array and put into another list.

  foreach (int[] integerarray in splitted)
    {
      //get the difference of the two highest numbers per integer array and place it on another List<int>
    }

    }
```

Comment: "how to continue." This is pretty broad. Where spercifically do you have difficulties? Finding the highest number in an array? Comparing two numbers? Putting an element into a list? ...?

Comment: add sample input and expected output. your question is not clear.

Comment: Two highest number in **which** array? You have a whole list of them.

Comment: If your array is sorted ascendly, the highest one is at index `Length - 1`, the second highest is at `Length - 2`. the difference between 2 numbers is HighestOne  - SecondHighestOne

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Updated. Added foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> get the difference between the two highest numbers in an integer array
>   and put into another list

You can use LINQ and `Math.Abs`:

```
List<int> differenceList = splitted
  .Select(list => list.OrderByDescending(i => i).Take(2).ToArray())
  .Select(highestTwo => Math.Abs(highestTwo[0] - highestTwo[1]))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Accepting this. Much better than my foreach proposal.